# Probability that $n$ participants are in $y$ games together?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have an interesting problem that I can't seem to work out. Ideally, I want to create a quick excel sheet for manipulating values.

Here is the scenario:

There are 'w' participants at an event.

There are 'x' games that the participants can play. (all participants want to play all the games)

Participants can only play 'y' games. (cannot play the same game more than once)

Each game can have 'z' participants.

What is the probability that 'n' participants are in 'y' games together?

Let:

w = 450

x = 10

y = 2

z = 50

n = 3

In real life, three of the participants have two games together. What is the probability of that happening?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to pick in your text something that makes a title reflecting at least a little more the content of your question (the former title "probability and statistics" wasn't very enlightning...). Besides, I don't see the connection with an Excel Sheet in your question...

Comment: Thanks for editing the title. Once I understand the equations and math to solve the problem, I want to create an excel sheet so I can easily adjust the variables based on the situation.